# How to avoid using while/cursor to achieve the same query results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to avoid looping from the below query.Now it takes long to retrieve the results from a table with 100000 records.

```
        @iMAX int, 
        @rowId int,
        @currCode varchar(20),
        @lastCode varchar(20),
        @amount money,
        @total money

  SET @rowId=1
  SET @iMAX=(Select count(RowId) from Table1)

WHILE(@rowId<=@iMAX)
  -- WHILE iteration
  BEGIN
        SELECT @Code=Code,@amount=Amount FROM Table1 WHERE RowId=@rowId
        if @lastCode is null or @lastCode <> @currCode
        begin 
              set @total = 0 
              set @lastCode = @currCode 
        end
        set @total = @total + @amount
        update Table1 set Balance = OpBalance + @total where RowId = @rowId

        SET @rowId=@rowId+1
  END
```

Comment: Could you add what you are trying to accomplish, your schema and some sample data and expected output?

Comment: You do an if statement on @lastCode but you don't set it. Is the setting just missing? Otherwise it's always null.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT *
        , total = SUM(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY RowId)
        , prevCode = LAG(Code) OVER (ORDER BY RowId)
    FROM dbo.Table1
)
UPDATE cte
SET Balance = OpBalance +
    CASE WHEN prevCode IS NULL OR prevCode != Code 
        THEN 0
        ELSE total
    END
```

Comment: How this section works in your query
set total = total + amount